# error undefined method `except' (NoMethodError) when attempting run vagrant up aws for the first time

Tags: linux, vagrant

I installed Vagrant on Linux, hoping to set it up for AWS.
I configured the Vagrantfile, tried 'running vagrant up'
but I'm getting error:
connect_aws.rb:41:in `call': undefined method` except' for #Hash:0x0000000002a4eeb0 (NoMethodError)

This is whats on line 41 of connect_aws.rb

'env[:aws_elb] = Fog::AWS::ELB.new(fog_config.except(:provider, :endpoint))'

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked it out for the time being.
I modified line 41 to just not refer to the exception (below).
At least it allows me to run vagrant up this time.

'env[:aws_elb] = Fog::AWS::ELB.new(fog_config)'